# Помогите перевести цикл на angular

Tags: angularjs

Kак с помощью ng-repeat получить значение по ключу

```
 for (var key in filters) {

        for (var i in filters[key]) {
         //как ангуляром получить вот это -> filters[key][i]

        }

    }
```

разметка

```
<div class="filter" id="{{h.name}}" title="Фильтр по {{h.title}}"> 
    <div ng-repeat="f in filters"></div> 
</div>
```

Фильтры

```
$scope.filters={ 
    "filters": {
        "Поле1":[
            "abc","edf","abw"
        ],
        "Поле2":[
            "dfe33","jj3","chdy3"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите разметку на которой вы это хотите применять, и пример `filters`

Comment: <div class="filter" id="{{h.name}}" title="Фильтр по {{h.title}}">
<div ng-repeat="f in filters"></div>
</div>

Comment: код и разметку добавляйте в вопрос

Comment: как ожидается результат выполнения? конечная разметка, для приведенного `filters`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) это прямой аналог цикла, если вы в коде пишете

```
for (var key in filters) {

    for (var i in filters[key]) {
     //как ангуляром получить вот это -> filters[key][i]

    }

}
```

то и в разметке это будет аналогично

```
<div ng-repeat="val in filters">
    <div ng-repeat="values in val">
        {{values}} - это аналог filters[key][i].
    </div>
</div>
```

Кроме того, если происходит итерация не только по массивам, но и по объектам и кроме значения поля нужно выводить еще и само название поля нужно использовать следующую конструкцию

```
(key, value) in expression
```

Answer (score 1):

В `div` с `ng-repeat` следует добавить `{{f}}`. К тому же, `$scope.filters` содержит всего одно значение - `"filters"`. Видимо, стоит написать `f in filters.filters` и всё будет работать.

Comment: да, но как мне написать вложенный ng-repeat, который пройдется по массиву объекта ` "Поле1":[
            "abc","edf","abw"
        ],`